# Which is the best method to install/uninstall apps in Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, software-installation, synaptic

While apps can be installed with the apt-get command, Synaptic Package Manager or Ubuntu Software Centre, can anybody throw some light on which is the best method? I recently installed kubuntu-desktop and as a result even Ubuntu Software Centre showed that it was installed. When I tried uninstalling it with Ubuntu Software Centre, the package didn't actually uninstall until I used Synaptic once again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most users, using the Ubuntu software center would be fine because it provides a simple GUI that allows to install and uninstall apps.  `sudo apt-get install` and `sudo apt-get remove` would also be good because they're the only commands in the terminal that don't make normal Ubuntu users feel frustrated.

But for advanced users, they might need to use Synaptic Package Manager because they only want to install or uninstall a specific package, like GTK.

So, for installing and uninstalling software, I would use the Software Center.

I would also use `sudo apt-get` if I can't install through the software center and `sudo apt-get --purge remove` to remove the software.  And for advanced removal, use Synaptic.

Comment: Just for clarity's sake, I'd like to mention that internally all of these tools do the same thing: they talk to apt, which installs software in Ubuntu. The only difference between them is the interface, where some tools provide more information (and control) than others.